# Traceur super call in constructor

Tags: ecmascript-6, traceur

I'm facing a problem with Traceur which seems to be related to the invocation of super() in a class constructor. I've managed to reduce the problem to the following code:

```
class BaseTest
{
    constructor()
    {
    }
}


class Test extends BaseTest
{   
    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }
}

var tc = new Test();
```

This causes a ModuleEvaluationError with the message 'undefined is not a function'. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

To clarify - the issue goes away if I comment out the `super();` call

Comment: Cannot reproduce with traceur 0.0.72.

Comment: According to package.json, this is version 0.0.73

Comment: It looks like I've been targeting an old traceur-runtime.js, not the one built by the project. All working now!